# Prove equality is the finest equivalence relation relation and Trivial relation is the coarsest relation

Tags: equivalence-relations

How it can be shown that:

> The equality equivalence relation is the [finest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Refinement_of_partitions) equivalence relation relation.

Since the equality relation denoted $R$ is an equivalence relation hence it should be a subset from the Cartesian product of two same  sets namely $X$,e.g.:

$$R⊆X×X$$

I know that we should pick an ordered pair $\left(x,y\right)∈R$  where $x,y∈X$ and show if it's an element of the equality equivalence relation $R$ then it's also contained in any other equivalence relations and using the definition of subset the result follows, but I don't know how exactly it can be done.

The other theorem states:

> The Trivial relation that makes all pairs of elements related is the [coarsest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#Refinement_of_partitions) relation.

The trivial relation denoted $R$ is a subset of Cartesian product of two subsets $S,T$, e.g.
$$R⊆S×T$$ and since every element in $R$ is related to the other elements so $R=S×T$

I don't know how to proof this one and any help is appreciated.
(Trivial relation is not necessarily a subset of Cartesian product of two same sets, hence it's not necessarily a homogeneous binary relation)

Comment: Can you please define 'finest' and 'coarsest' in your question?

Comment: For the first, recognize that every equivalence relation is reflexive.  For the second, recognize that every equivalence relation is a relation and thus a subset of $S\times T$.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22, I will add a link for that

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 these are very standard terms... if you have two relations, $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$, then $A$ is "finer" than $B$ and $B$ is "coarser" than $A$.  In layman's terms, $A$ is more specific than $B$.  For example "starts with the same first three letters" is finer than "starts with the same letter."

Comment: @JMoravitz,I don't know how to use them

Comment: @user715522 Every reflexive relation on $X$ must for every $x\in X$ include $(x,x)$ in the relation (*among possibly many more pairs*), otherwise it wouldn't be reflexive.  Phrase it in a correct way as to imply that $Id_X \subseteq A$ for every possible equivalence relation $A$ over $X$.

Comment: There can **be** no finer equivalence relation since equality is the **finest** possible reflexive relation on a set. There can **be** no coarser relation since the trivial relation is the **coarsest** possible relation.

Comment: @JMoravitz, I got the first one, thank you

Comment: @Somos, well the statement that claim " trivial relation is the coarsest possible relationt" need a proof

Comment: For the second, recall as I said in my first comment that every relation over $S\times T$ will be by definition a subset of $S\times T$ based on what it means to be a relation in the first place.  You say you showed and understand that the trivial relation where everything is related to everything else, $R$, satisfies that $R=S\times T$.  So... since every other relation is a subset of $S\times T$... don't you see why that means that every other relation is a subset of $R$?  After all... $R$ and $S\times T$ are equal, aren't they?  And then why this implies that $R$ is coarser than any $A$?

Comment: @JMoravitz, I understand, thanks again

Comment: @JMoravitz, sorry but in the first one I guess you showed that identity relation is the finest equivalence relation but you did not show that **equality** is the finest (In my opinion identity relation is the finest), well I think since every ordered pair are in the form (x,x) this is actually the same as identity relation)

Comment: @user715522 the equality equivalence relation **is** the identity equivalence relation.  They are two names for the same thing.

Comment: thank you so much for your responding,intuitively I agree with  that but in there proof of that?